# adding image inside dynamically created circle in canvas Android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, paint

I am trying to create a hollow circle and then put image inside it. I have imageview statically in my XML file. But the hollow circle I am creating is dynamically with the use of Paint class.

The issue is I can draw both and are visible but when I put hollow circle over image it overlaps imageview and image is not visible.

Another issue is I do not know how to put both of them in center of layout. 
Here is my java code snippet

```
 RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel);
    Circle view = new Circle(MyActivity.this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    rl.addView(view);
```

Code to draw circle

```
 private class Circle extends  View {
    public Circle(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle((int) (500), (int) (430),
                320, mPaint);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle((int) (500), (int) (430),
                300, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help to define both image inside this circle in Center I know it need to pass x, y coordinates while drawing circle here but how to know center(x,y) - radius coordinate for circle. Thanks

Comment: Why not using this readymade circleimageview https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: No I have some extra needs as well that does not fit for me